# Math expression simplify for least operations

Tags: math, optimization

I have a math expression and I want to simplify it, if it's posible, to make it have the least operations and thus be the fastest to calculate. I'm not interested in precision, just speed. I found many online sites that simplifies math expression but only for human readable purpose, not computer. Is there any algorithm/method to do so?
Btw one of my expressions is:
`a(a*x+b*y+c*z)+d(d*x-b*z+c*y)+z(d*y-c*x+a*z)-b(d*z-a*y+b*x)`
rest is similar.

Comment: And you do not trust your compiler why?

Comment: @AlexP becouse i don't use compiler (even if i did i think only really advanced, like c#, woluld handle that). I'm programming something external, that isn't... very fast.

Comment: And what are those variables? Scalars? 1D-arrays / Vectors?

Comment: So... what, are you programming assembly? This is going to depend on hardware details, like how many registers you have. Working in terms of expressions at all is probably going to be suboptimal, since an expression can't capture things like common subexpression elimination or register pressure.

Comment: Then do it by hand by finding common subexpressions. If I'm not mistaken your example is equivalent to `aax + 2aby + (c + z)(az + dy) - bbx - 2bdz - cxz`.

Comment: wolframalpha offers quite clear alternative forms for these kinds of equations. It even solves and gives you the roots, derivatives and integrals as well as the plot(if there is one)

Comment: These variables are floats. Nope, that isn't assembly (I wrote it isn't fast) and it's rather high level, just very slow. Any operatins I can get from that are simply + - * / (which in my case have the same speed, so I count them as equal), i just want to have them the least.

Comment: @AlexP yeah, there is reduction from 27 to 22 operations if I counted rigth which is something. Though I have 2 cases more and just for being sure that i have the best resoult I would rather prefer some kind of algorithm.

Comment: List all your partial products. Count how many times each of them appears. If more than one, it is a common subexpression.

Comment: Term rewriting is useful to find local minima, as far as I know full-minimization can only be done by brute force but I hope there's something I've missed.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with

```
a*(a*x+b*y+c*z)+d*(d*x-b*z+c*y)+z*(d*y-c*x+a*z)-b*(d*z-a*y+b*x)
```

that has 16 multiplications and 11 additions/subtractions.

The third bracket looks a bit odd having z as a multiplier, I might have expected a constant c here.

If we expand

```
a*a*x+a*b*y+a*c*z+d*d*x-d*b*z+d*c*y+z*d*y-c*x*z+a*z*z-b*d*z-a*b*y+b*b*x
```

it goes up to 24 multiplications and 11 additions/subtractions.

Grouping by powers of x,y,z

```
(a*a+d*d+b*b)*x-c*x*z+(a*b+d*c-a*b)*y+d*y*z+(a*c-d*b-b*d)*z+a*z*z
```

Gives 18 multiplications and 11 additions. We could have gone to

```
(a*a+d*d+b*b-c*z)*x+(a*b+d*c-a*b+d*z)*y+(a*c-d*b-b*d+a*z)*z
```

With 15 multiplications and 11 additions. There is some simplification
as the a*b*y cancel and there are two d*b*z's.

```
(a*a+d*d+b*b-c*z)*x+(d*c+d*z)*y+(a*c-2*d*b+a*z)*z
```

13 multiplications 8 additions.

Some further grouping

```
(a*a+d*d+b*b-c*z)*x+(c+z)*d*y+(a*(c+z)-2*d*b)*z
```

drops to 11 multiplications 8 additions. There is a common c+z terms so we could use a tempory variable

```
c_z = c+z
(a*a+d*d+b*b-c*z)*x+c_z*d*y+(a*c_z-2*d*b)*z
```

11 multiplications and 7 additions. Which, I think, is the best you are going to get.

The first thing to note is that this is not substantially better than the initial version. 18 operations compared to 27, maybe saving a third of the evaluation time. You may well find that this is not the bottleneck in your program.

There is an algorithm called [Horner's Rule](https://www.math10.com/en/algebra/horner.html) which can simplify the evaluation of polynomials. This tends to work better if you have higher powers of a single variable.

The above suggests an algorithm

1. expand all terms to form a set of monomials, cancel terms and collect like terms
2. Find the most frequent symbol, say x
3. Group using that symbol.
4. repeat 2

So in your case expanding gives

```
a*a*x+a*b*y+a*c*z+d*d*x-d*b*z+d*c*y+z*d*y-c*x*z+a*z*z-b*d*z-a*b*y+b*b*x
```

cancelling and collecting like terms

```
a*a*x+a*c*z+d*d*x+d*c*y+z*d*y-c*x*z+a*z*z-2*b*d*z+b*b*x
```

find most common symbol, say `x`, group using that

```
(a*a+d*d-c*z+b*b)*x+a*c*z+d*c*y+z*d*y+a*z*z-2*b*d*z
```

repeat. Common symbol is `z`,

```
(a*a+d*d-c*z+b*b)*x+(a*c+d*y+a*z-2*b*d)*z+d*c*y
```

repeat. This time the most common symbol is the `a` inside the second bracket.

```
(a*a+d*d-c*z+b*b)*x+((c+z)*a+d*y-2*b*d)*z+d*c*y
```

repeat again, this time the most common symbol is `d`

```
(a*a+d*d-c*z+b*b)*x+((c+z)*a+(y-2*b)*d)*z+d*c*y
```

Giving a version with 11 multiplications and 8 additions/subtractions.

An alternative for the first common symbols was `d`

```
a*a*x+a*c*z+d*d*x+d*c*y+z*d*y-c*x*z+a*z*z-2*b*d*z+b*b*x
```

d

```
a*a*x+a*c*z+ (d*x+c*y+z*y-2*b*z)*d-c*x*z+a*z*z+b*b*x
```

x

```
(a*a-c*z+b*b)*x+a*c*z+ (d*x+c*y+z*y-2*b*z)*d+a*z*z
```

a

```
(a*a-c*z+b*b)*x+(c*z+z*z)*a+ (d*x+c*y+z*y-2*b*z)*d
```

z

```
(a*a-c*z+b*b)*x+((c+z)*z)*a+ (d*x+c*y+(y-2*b)*z)*d
```

Again a solution with 11 multiplications and 8 additions/subtractions.

Comment: Thanks for long explanation. Though I found better solution for my programm so if it will work, I won't need that anymore.

Comment: So why not upvote it if you are thankful (not necessarily accepting)?